# $L^{1}([a,b],m)$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I want to prove that $L^{1}([a,b],m)$ is uniformly integrable. That is the space of integrable functions on $[a,b]$ is uniformly integrable with the space having measure $m$.

Let $f\in L^{1}([a,b],m)$. Then $\displaystyle\int_a^b|f|dm<\infty$. Also, $f$ is finite almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. Suppose $A\subset[a,b]$ is the set on which $f$ is finite. Then, $$\displaystyle\int_a^b|f|dm=\int_A|f|dm+\int_{A^c}|f|dm=\int_A|f|dm<\infty$$
since $m(A^c)=0.$

Let $M=\text{max}\{|f(x)|:x\in A \}$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=M/\epsilon$. If $m(A)<\delta$  then, $$\int_A|f|dm\leq Mm(A)< \epsilon$$Is this proof fine? Thank you

Comment: How do you know that maximum exists??

Comment: Take $f(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{x}}$ with $a=0,b=1$. Then $\sup |f| = \infty$.

Comment: How can a linear space be uniformly integrable?

Comment: @copper.hat I think what he means is absolute continuity.

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology. $L^1[a,b]$ is certainly not uniformly integrable. You seem to be proving that if  $f\in L^1,$ then $\int_A f$ has a certain "absolute continuity" property. Furthermore you have a strange idea: that $f\in L^1$ implies $f$ is bounded?

Comment: @zhw where did I say $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Let $M=\text{max}\{|f(x)|:x\in A \}$

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam: I believe you are correct. I thought the OP might have omitted some part of the question.

Comment: @zhw. $f$ is finite in A

Comment: It's not true that every function that is finite valued on a set is bounded on that set. Example: $f(x) =x$ on $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $M_n=\{x \in [a,b]:|f(x)| \ge n\}$. Then $$n\mu(M_n)\le\int_{M_n}|f|d\mu \le \int_{[a,b]}|f|d\mu =K\lt \infty$$ gives that $\mu(M_n) \le \frac{K}{n}$ and therefore goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Observe that $M_{n+1} \subset M_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $M=\cap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} M_n$. Then $\mu(M)=0$.

You can show that $E \to \int_E|f|d\mu$ is a measure and therefore $$0=\int_M|f|d\mu=\lim_n\int_{M_n}|f|d\mu$$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$. Let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2n_0}$. Then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$, $$\int_{M_n}|f|d\mu \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Whenever $\mu(A) \lt \delta$, we have $$\int_A|f|d\mu=\int_{A \cap M_{n_0}}|f|d\mu+\int_{A \cap {M_{n_0}}^c}|f|d\mu \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}+n_0\delta \lt \epsilon$$

Comment: So what have you proved here? That $f$s are uniformly integrable?

Comment: I just corrected that flaw. You can always find a set in which $f$ is not bounded and integrate over it to make it small. In its complement, it is bounded.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam No, $f$ is not absolutely continuous, we only know $f\in L^1.$ However the measure $\lambda (A) = \int_A f d\mu$ is AC.

Comment: @Heisenberg Uniform integrability is for a set of functions. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability. I just saw your proof and assumed that you want to show this: For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that whenever $\mu(A) \lt \delta$, we have $|\int_Afd\mu| \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you. Corrected it.